# undefined method error when accessing class page object from module

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I'm trying to access class method which is defined in `Module`, I can call function but function has page object element which performs some operation like click, I'm getting following error:

```
undefined method "label_year" for Datefunctions:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Here's my files structure:

`./lib/calender_util.rb`:

```ruby
module CalenderUtil
    def set_date
        Datefunctions.get_calender_year
    end
end
class Datefunctions
    include PageObject
    span(:label_year, :class=> 'ui-datepicker-year')
    span(:label_month, :class=> 'ui-datepicker-month')

   def self.get_calender_year
      return label_year
   end
end
```

`./home_page.rb`:

```ruby
require 'calender_helper.rb'
include CalenderUtil

 def setTravelDate date
    CalenderUtil.set_date
 end
```

parts of `env.rb`:

```ruby
require 'page-object'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/../../lib'

require 'calender_helper.rb'
include CalenderHelper

World PageObject::PageFactory
World CalenderHelper
```

In addition; I've defined include/require multiple times I'll take off once this solved.

Comment: Where does `label_year` method come from? I don't see its implementation in the code you provided.

Comment: label_year is an element on webpage like div text, PageObject gem define these elements by span(:label_year, :class=> 'ui-datepicker-month') so we can access them by simply 'label_year'

Comment: The problem is that `label_year` is an instance method while `get_calender_year` is a class method. If you can clarify what you are trying to achieve (ie example of how you are using the calender util), I could try giving a solution.

Comment: @JustinKo : I'm calling in homepage.rb like 'CalenderUtil.set_date' let me know if u need complete homepage.rb file

Comment: @StaleElementException, I guess my confusion is why you want a CalenderUtil outside of the page object. The calender is on the page, so it makes more sense to me to be including those methods within a page object and then interacting directly with that page object. For example, I would think the cucumber test would be doing `page.label_year.should == '1/1/2013'` rather than `CalenderUtil.get_calender_year.should == '1/1/2013'`.

Comment: @JustinKo i want make lib of utilities which i can use across frameworks

Comment: @JustinKo this is just my prototype for automation framework also im new to ruby, if this way doesn't work will opt better solution

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, the methods auto-generated by PageObject, are all instance methods. You can't use it in a class method because there is no instance.

Look at the doc's example:

```
class LoginPage
  include PageObject

  text_field(:username, :id => 'username')
  text_field(:password, :id => 'password')
  button(:login, :id => 'login')
end

login_page.username = 'cheezy'
login_page.password = 'secret'
login_page.login
```

The methods are for instances.

To fix, you need to create an instance.

```
module CalenderUtil
  def set_date
    page = Datefunctions.new(args_foo)
    page.label_year
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `label_year` is an instance method while `get_calender_year` is a class method. You cannot call the instance method since you have not created an instance of the class.

As Billy Chan pointed out, for your code to work, you need to create an instance of the Datefunctions class within your module. This seems a bit awkward since you would need to pass the browser instance to each method called in the CalenderUtil. To me CalenderUtil is a layer of abstraction that is not adding any value.

I think that you should:

1. Use modules to encapsulate controls that are used across multiple pages.
2. Include these modules within the page object classes that have the controls.
3. Call the methods from the page objects.

For your example, I would create a Datefunctions module that defines the datepicker controls.

```
module DateFunctions
  include PageObject
  span(:label_year, :class=> 'ui-datepicker-year')
  span(:label_month, :class=> 'ui-datepicker-month')
end
```

Then for each page class that uses the datepicker control, include the module:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject
  include DateFunctions
end
```

In your tests, I assume it is Cucumber but the same is true for whatever framework, use the method from the page object.

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
page.label_year.should == '1/1/2013'
```

Comment: can we use PageObject with Module?

Comment: That is what Billy's answer shows. Note that you have to pass the browser to the module's methods.